# Corrupted SVN repo - checkout resulting in invalid XML error

Tags: wordpress, svn

I manage a WordPress plugin and since the last commit, the repository cannot be accessed.

```
svn checkout https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/acymailing-integration-for-memberpress
A    acymailing-integration-for-memberpress/assets
A    acymailing-integration-for-memberpress/tags
svn: E175009: The XML response contains invalid XML
svn: E130003: Malformed XML: not well-formed (invalid token) at line 55
```

What I suspect causes this problem is the folder [https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/acymailing-integration-for-memberpress/tags/_[C2.2/](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/acymailing-integration-for-memberpress/tags/_%5BC2.2/) that should have been https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/acymailing-integration-for-memberpress/tags/2.2/ instead, due to a typo.

Is there a way to remove this folder? Or force SVN to ignore the error so that I could remove/rename this folder?

I have tried using the command lines and smartSVN on Mac, and TortoiseSVN on Windows but the same error appears each time.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reaching to the Plugins team via email / Slack? They may be able to help you sort this out.

Comment: I haven't since they already have more than 50 days of response time for plugin reviews.
But I found a solution by switching to my Windows computer and using TortoiseSVN that lets you checkout only the folders without their content. I then removed the tags/ folder, committed then re-added it with only the "correct" content and it worked out well: the problematic folder has been removed.

Comment: Might want to answer your own question then, explaining in detail what you did as it might help others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to remove the "corrupted" folder by switching to a Windows computer and using TortoiseSVN to checkout only the base folders without their content.

I then removed the tags/ folder, committed then re-added a tags/ folder with only the correct content.